# How can I access a specific cell of array in For In of a different array?

Tags: python, arrays

I want to add only digits of a number. I managed to divide a number into digits but I don't know how I could make this work? I want to access two arrays at the same time.

It just gives me IndexError: list index out of range

```
t=[]
t=[int(i) for i in str(a)]
d=[]
d=[int(i) for i in str(b)]
c=0
for i in t:
    c=c+1
    t[c]=(t[c]+d[c])%10
```

If t=[1, 2] and d=[3, 4] then I would like t=[4, 6]

Comment: look at `zip` to access both lists simultaneously

Comment: You might also note that you are having lists, not arrays.

Comment: The problem here is that the index (the variable `c`) is being updated before being used to access `t` and `d`. This code will try to access t[2] on the second iteration which is out of the range of the lists in your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `zip()` which helps you iterate over two lists at the same time:

```
t = [x + y for x, y in zip(t, d)]
```

A corrected, non-recommended code is:

```
# ...
for i in t:
    t[c] = (t[c] + d[c]) % 10
    c += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can use numpy to addition arrays
np.array([1, 2]) + np. array([3, 4])